# WMS tile caching for QGIS Server

Tags: openlayers, geowebcache, qgis-server, cache

I recently migrated some map services from Geoserver to QGIS Server and up till now everything works quite nice. I only miss the possibility to cache tiles, mostly used by Openlayers.

Is there any alternative to GeoWebCache for QGIS Server? I see I could use its standalone version but want to avoid Java and Tomcat on the server. So what would be the best alternatives?

I would prefer any open source alternative written in PHP or Python. So far I had a look on [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/doc/#url-template-provider), but before giving it a shot I wanted to hear your recommendations.

Comment: what about mapproxy?

Comment: looks quite promising, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Mapproxy is a great tool and after playing around with it a while I definitely can recommend it to everybody looking for a effective and reliable tile caching engine together with QGIS Server.

Comment: you should add this as an answer for the benefit of future searchers